# How do I update the GUI from another thread? using python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

What is the best way to update a gui from another thread in python.

I have main function (GUI) in `thread1` and from this i'm referring another thread (`thread2`), is it possible to update GUI  while working in `Thread2` without cancelling work at `thread2`, if it is yes how can I do that?

any suggested reading about thread handling. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use Threading to run several processes simultaneously.

You have to create a class like this :

```
from threading import Thread

class Work(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self): # This function launch the thread
        (your code)
```

if you want run several thread at the same time :

```
def foo():
    i = 0
    list = []
    while i < 10:
        list.append(Work())
        list[i].start() # Start call run() method of the class above.
        i += 1
```

Be careful if you want to use the same variable in several threads. You must lock this variable so that they do not all reach this variable at the same time. Like this :

```
lock = threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()
try:
    yourVariable += 1 # When you call lock.acquire() without arguments, block all variables until the lock is unlocked (lock.release()).
finally:
    lock.release()
```

From the main thread, you can call join() on the queue to wait until all pending tasks have been completed.

This approach has the benefit that you are not creating and destroying threads, which is expensive. The worker threads will run continuously, but will be asleep when no tasks are in the queue, using zero CPU time.

I hope it will help you.